# How to remove permission of azure devops pipeline from an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I deploy .net web app via azure pipelines onto IIS on an azure vm via the web deploy task.

To do this I had to initially configure the deployment group by running a script on the azure vm as explained here (see step 5): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops&tabs=net#create-a-deployment-group

The project has completed and now I want to remove the permission of the pipeline to the azure vm. How to remove the permission of azure devops pipeline from an Azure VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The project has completed and now I want to remove the permission of the pipeline to the azure vm.

DevOps pipeline uses the account(when you setup agent, default is "nt authority\system") to access the agent.

[image]

You can uninstall the deployment group agent to remove the access:

1. Launch powershell,go to agent folder.
2. Run `.\config.cmd remove` to uninstall.

After it's done, it will remove the agent service and also VSTS group user below.

[image]

If you specify user not default, you can even directly delete the user from the machine to remove the permission.

Comment: After the uninstallation, is it then possible to re-use this VM as a deployment target for another pipeline?

Comment: After uninstallation, the machine is not longer the  agent machine any more. You need to reconfigure it as agent machine so that it can be used for pipeline, whatif current one or new pipeline.