# Manage IISApplication Pool Azuredevops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a pipeline in. Netcore
I successfully ran the build but upon creating release, it fails with the error. The error occurred in IIS Web App Manage task here is the log error in Azure devops

C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe stop apppool/apppool.name:" Name of the pool"
Error ( message: Cannot find APPPOOL object with identifier "nameofthepool"

Please help need solution to solve this.

##error Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '1168'

Comment: What is your pipeline YAML?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, please check:

1. the devops account has permission to stop the site pool. The default account should be `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` on local agent.

[image]

You can add a command line task with command `whoami` to check which user is used for devops pipeline. It's recommended to change the user to `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` as it has permission to stop the pool. You can check the details in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72698070/14996050).

2. Go to IIS manager, make sure the pool `nameofthepool` exists.

I confirm the pool can be stopped successfully on my side.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Komal, how is it going? thanks.